# geoserver 2.10 fresh install getting "HTTP ERROR: 503 Problem accessing /geoserver/. Reason: Service Unavailable"

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to run the platform independent geoserver 2.10 under rhel6 using oracle java 1.8. 
Jetty starts and when I try to go to /geoserver/ I get

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /geoserver/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty://
```

This what comes out on standard output.

```
bin/startup.sh 
GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /SOMEDIR/geoserver-2.10.2/data_dir
WARNING: Module not found [ssl]
2017-03-23 17:27:40.642:INFO::main: Logging initialized @324ms
2017-03-23 17:27:40.838:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
2017-03-23 17:27:40.859:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/geoserver-2.10.2/webapps/] at interval 1
2017-03-23 17:27:41.684:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:42 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:42 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:42 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:42 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [geoserverlogfile].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
2017-03-23 17:27:42.542:INFO:geoserver:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:43 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:43 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:43 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Mar 23, 2017 5:27:43 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
"
Then it starts loading files and eventually I get this. 
2017-03-23 17:27:50.952:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7e0ea639{/geoserver,file:/home/geoserver-2.10.2/webapps/geoserver/,STARTING}{/geoserver}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error occured reading security configuration; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.reload(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:441)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.onApplicationEvent(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:376)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.getMasterPassword(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1881)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.assertActivatedKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:234)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.reloadKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:101)
        at org.geoserver.security.concurrent.LockingKeyStoreProvider.reloadKeyStore(LockingKeyStoreProvider.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:592)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:583)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.reload(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:434)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.onApplicationEvent(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:376)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: 
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:708)
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:912)
        at org.geoserver.security.password.URLMasterPasswordProvider.decode(URLMasterPasswordProvider.java:134)
        at org.geoserver.security.password.URLMasterPasswordProvider.doGetMasterPassword(URLMasterPasswordProvider.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.security.MasterPasswordProvider.getMasterPassword(MasterPasswordProvider.java:35)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.getMasterPassword(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1879)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.assertActivatedKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:234)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.reloadKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:101)
        at org.geoserver.security.concurrent.LockingKeyStoreProvider.reloadKeyStore(LockingKeyStoreProvider.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:592)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:583)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.reload(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:434)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.onApplicationEvent(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:376)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.nextSpi(SecretKeyFactory.java:295)
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:121)
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:160)
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:695)
        at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:912)
        at org.geoserver.security.password.URLMasterPasswordProvider.decode(URLMasterPasswordProvider.java:134)
        at org.geoserver.security.password.URLMasterPasswordProvider.doGetMasterPassword(URLMasterPasswordProvider.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.security.MasterPasswordProvider.getMasterPassword(MasterPasswordProvider.java:35)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.getMasterPassword(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1879)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.assertActivatedKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:234)
        at org.geoserver.security.KeyStoreProviderImpl.reloadKeyStore(KeyStoreProviderImpl.java:101)
        at org.geoserver.security.concurrent.LockingKeyStoreProvider.reloadKeyStore(LockingKeyStoreProvider.java:80)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:592)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.init(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:583)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.reload(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:434)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.onApplicationEvent(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:376)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
        at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
        at 
.
.
.    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
2017-03-23 17:27:50.972:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2a9ea03f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8888}
2017-03-23 17:27:50.973:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @10655ms
```

Comment: is this a clean install, or do you have an existing data directory? did you previously have strong encryption set and now haven't installed it?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue while attempting to run geoserver without administrator privileges.

```
sudo -u root -i
```

and all was good.

Comment: Where do you type this?

Comment: @ViktorSulakvelidze-Skantz in command line, before running the program

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Windows 10. I saw that Java was starting well but not Geoserver. Reading the answer above by @tony I realized I could try to "run as administrator" (right click menu). That solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

In my case i uninstalled geoserver and java jre, then reinstalled a java jre for 32 bits (i have installed a 64 bits version, that was the error).

Apparently you need a 32 bits java jre when you install geoserver as windows services.

You are using rhel6 but probably the same solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run the "startup.bat" file as an administrator.
[image]

Comment: Note the question is about a Linux installation, not a Windows installation.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your note!

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. In fact, Geoserver couldn't detect JRE in the installation directory. However, your solution pointed me in the right direction. I used the JRE installer recommended by the Geoserver installation wizard and it worked. Simply visit https://adoptium.net/ and select "Temurin 8 (LTS)" because Geoserver only supports Java 8.